# Unable to access CodeCommit repo using username password inside URL

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, git-clone, aws-codecommit

I want to clone codecommit repo using username password inside clone URL. I am using following

URL:

```
git clone https://username:password@git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/sample-repo
```

But I am getting this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://username:password@git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/sample-repo/'                      : Port number ended with 'c'

whereas this method worked for another account without issue, is there any permission issue on credentials.

Comment: Username or password contains special characters that cause this?

Comment: But same username password worked, when I user git clone simple URL

Comment: Can you `git clone` the repository without username and password in the `git clone` command? Or does the error message appear?

Comment: yes, then it asks username and password, when I enter it works fine.

Comment: And your password doesn't have any special characters like `%` or `&`? Or do you write the email address as username with the `@` sign?

Comment: No its not having special character. not using email as username. password having only = sign and + sign. username having - and /

Comment: I think error is due to forward slash / in password, what do u say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed special character / from password and replaced it with escape character that fixed my problem.

```
Escape Character for / is %2F
```